# Does any app/software takes up all the RAM while running that is required to run it smoothly

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, kali-linux

I was running **Kali Linux Virtual Machine** on my **4GB Windows 10** laptop and when I opened task manager, I saw **virtual machine was not running on 1/2 GB RAM that is minimum requirement**, so does any app/software takes up all the RAM that is required while running ?

Comment: Minimum requirements are in place so that the suggested software does not crash the operating system it is being used on. Like Windows 10 itself, it has the min. requirement in place before it will even install the software so it will not crash.

Comment: @vssher Does it takes up the RAM required while running ?

Comment: No, not usually, this is just a minimum requrement so it won't crash and ruin your existing hardware/software.